# Disable hellobar JS thru code (killswitch)

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

Hi we use hellobar (popup lead generator)

Now sometimes we dont want a certain visitor to see ANY Hellobar (NONE)

So we would like to add some kind of killswitch ... for this purpose we have set a cookie thinking that we can do this `if (cookie) then { kill HB or do something }`

This used to work in the past when we set a cookie with name HBDismissed only this does not work anymore. And yes we have asked helloabr to change it back ... but after 4-6 months I decided to check some other method. There must be a way to influence the HB object.

**question**: how can I disable the complete hellobar workings based on a cookie (or some other check) ...

Comment: Have you tried using jQuery session? If you know who the user is, or some other vector, that person gets a no-hello-bar session, and on page load an if else says don't load hello-bar on that page if session == 1 (exists).

Comment: Almost clear - not just ... How do I get al session to show first in console?

Comment: Not sure why you want to but you can link the session being active to a variable, then say console.log(sessionVariable); to report it to the browser console. The value you will get on successful session is the number 1. Which visitors do you not want to show the hellobar to?

Comment: May I revive this? .... the question is: what is the exact code or object to influence to stop! the hellobar from doing anyhting?

Comment: I gave this a go in an Answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way I've posted all code to codepen https://codepen.io/dirtandrust/pen/wELzem because it causes a security error in Stack Overflow's built-in editor. Here's the code, explanation to follow:

HTML:

```
    <div class="session--storage-box hide">Storage box here <span class="close">&times;</span></div>
```

CSS:

```
.session--storage-box {
        background: #efefef;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 5em;
    }

.session--storage-box.hide {
            display: none;
        }

    .close {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

JQUERY:

```
"use strict";

$(document).ready(function() {

    if (!sessionStorage.alreadyClicked) {
        $('.session--storage-box').removeClass('hide');
    }

});

$(document).on('click', '.close', function() {

    $('.session--storage-box').fadeTo(300, 0, function() {
        $('.session--storage-box').addClass('hide');
        sessionStorage.alreadyClicked = 1;
    });

});
```

- Make a div and hide it using css by default. You can put the Hellobar code here and it will hide but will still load, unfortunately; but at least your users won't see it after they close the div it's in.
- CSS to show and hide the div hellobar code is in
- JS/jQuery to give the user a sessionStorage which you can inspect in a browser like Firefox's console/Network/Session Storage; in this example I see "alreadyClicked=1" in my console

An even better way, I can imagine, is to tie your user's login to this preference instead and then you can wire your View to not even load the Hellobar script if the user doesn't want it.